# Multiple Memberships on one contact ID, different orgs?

Tags: civimember

A member has a life membership and now wants to add a second membership (a magazine subscription). I believe previously you needed to create a dummy organisation to house ("own") the second subscription. Is this still the case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe that is still the standard workaround.